# How to make LALR(1) directly?

Tags: graphs

I studied LR(1) parsers and then LALR(1) and noticed that if we wanna construct LALR(1), We should FIRST construct the LR(1) parser and then by combining states we can go ahead for LALR(1) parser.

Now a question comes in my mind, Can we make LALR(1) parser **DIRECTLY**? Without using (Or constructing LR(1) parser) ? If Yes, How?

Thanks in advance!